# How tho check in Java if there is same characters in a String?

Tags: java, string

I've got a 6 char long string, and I would like to check, if there is just one from each character. How to?

Comment: Please give example input and code you are trying

Comment: More expansive explanation for working with strings you can have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm
and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a `Set`. You need unique elements and `Set` gurantees you containing the unique elements. `HashSet` is implementation of `Set`, you can use it to implement this idea.

```
public boolean ifAllCharsUnique(String input){
    char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
    int length = arr.length;
    Set<Character> checker = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i =0 ; i < length; i++){
         if(checker.contains(arr[i]){
               return false;
         }
         checker.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: With this method, I create a new array (or ArrayList ? )  < checker > , which only contains unique characters?

Answer (score 3):

You could compare the number of distinct characters to the length of the string:

```
boolean charMoreThanOnce = s.chars().distinct().count() < s.length();
```

Comment: As much as I like such nice, clean, precise answers; I still feel tempted to not upvote; as this very much looks like you just did somebody's homework. Not that he will be able to make much out of this, but still.

Comment: Is it splitting hairs to point out that [it doesn't work for `""`](http://ideone.com/dyN8ym)?